# How is it that Cronbach’s alpha for these 3 variables is so low, but using them to create a latent variable to predict a DV has such a high R2?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, cronbachs-alpha

**TL;DR:
3 variables score low on cronbach’s alpha but are very effective at predicting a DV when grouped as a latent variable.**

I am analyzing screenplays and I used software that would classify screenplays on a variety of psychological (e.g, aggressive, reward, risk, negative) dimensions. So a score of 0.10 for reward means that 10% of the meaningful language dealt with rewards.

My hypothesis was that people who are what is commonly called "Type-A" will be more analytic - which is a dimension, my DV. So TYPEA was a latent variable. It was comprised of (1) REWARD, (2) RISK, (3) POWER. And using TYPEA to predict ANALYTIC yielded an R2 of 0.79.

However, when when I ran cronbach’s alpha on those 3 variables to justify my TYPEA scale/latent variable, the scale reliability coefficient was just 0.25

Can somebody explain how this can be the case?

Comment: TL;DR. Predictors don't need to intercorrelate at all in order to be able to predict a predictand by 100%, when taken together (for example summed). Actually, low-correlated indicators which in combination do predict an external criterion well are called a _battery_, not a _latent_ construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but this is what I believe is happening: Normally the reliability between two observed variables limits how strongly these variables can be observed to correlate with each other. Since a lot of models are designed to estimate "true effect sizes" (or in other words the relationships between latent constructs) they correct for this. It's called [correction for attenuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correction_for_attenuation). When it's a correlation between two measures you divide that correlation by the square root of the product of the reliabilities of these two measures. 
$$r_{x'y'} = \frac{r_{xy}}{\sqrt{r_{xx}r_{yy}}}$$ Where $r_{xy}$ is the observed correlation and $r_{xx}$ and $r_{yy}$ are the reliabilities. I suspect your model is doing something similar (though not necessarily exactly this); weak correlations between measures with low reliabilities are turning into strong assumed/extrapolated "true explained variances".